# Subfigures in subsequent frames

Tags: subfloats

I have three subfigures and I want to include two of them in one frame and the third in the next frame. How can I do it?

Comment: When you say frame, do we assume that your document class is beamer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.